# Rails - Command "bundle install" can't fetch gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I always get an error when trying to install all gems of a given app.

```
$ bundle install --verbose --retry 4
Fetching from: https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...Fetching from: https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/sass-rails-4.0.3.gemspec.rz

Network error while fetching https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/sass-rails-4.0.3.gemspec.rz
```

I can fetch the file manually via wget or a web browser, so the network is not an issue !

Installing via the gem command works too but that's a pain.

Can someone help me on this one ? I'm clueless to what could be happening here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am newbie, learning RoR, Running Mavericks, Trying it using RVM, Ruby version 2.1.2, Rails 4.1.4

When I tried running `$ rails server`, I was getting the below errors

and I have tried this being in my rails app folder

*Network error while fetching
https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/sass-rails-4.0.3.gemspec.rz*

```
$ gem install spring
```

*Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.*

```
$ gem install jquery-rails
```

*Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.*

```
$ gem install sqlite3
```

*Could not find gem 'sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.*

```
$ gem install sass-rails
```

**And for other errors like above I did install them one by one**

I couldn't find any solution over the internet, even my system gems are updated. Then as a last resort I did this, installing them one by one.

And it started working

Comment: Yes you can install them one by one but that's a real pain. I don't want to be doing this but rather fix that bugging problem. Thanks for the tip anyway